# Function proto types / declarations for UxTheme.dll -dynamic- loading

Tags: c++, c, dll, c++builder

Using c++ Builder 2009, I am trying to fix a Pre-Theme OS issue with the code, namely "UxTheme.dll" not found during start of the program, on Windows 2000.

This because of the use of a number of functions:

```
OpenThemeData
DrawThemeBackground
DrawThemeEdge
CloseThemeData
GetThemePartSize
```

And because the code includes `#include <UxTheme.hpp>` (that in turn includes: `#include "uxtheme.h"`) and the project links `UxTheme.lib` that loads the dll statically.

My (initial) aim is to disable functionality that requires these functions on an OS that does not have this dll, but for that I need to load UxTheme.dll dynamically (`LoadLibrary()`) and get addresses for the required functions (`GetProcAddress()`). 
If the dll or the functions can't be loaded I can disable the functionality or assign my own dummy functions, and the nasty startup error goes away.

I'm having trouble understanding the exact syntax needed of the function prototypes to be able to use `GetProcAddress()` etc.  So my first question is, does anybody know of a header file that contains all this information already, and/or a c(pp) file that does the function pointer assigning, in the public domain.  Alternatively, can somebody give me the header and cpp syntax example for one of the functions (e.g. `DrawThemeBackground`) and I should be able to figure out the rest !  And do I still include `<UxTheme.hpp>` then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needed some trial an error from my part but `__stdcall` was the calling convention that I needed.  I had tried `__cdecl` before, but this (obviously) didn't work.

.h

```
HTHEME (__stdcall *OpenThemeData)(
    HWND hwnd,
    LPCWSTR pszClassList
    );

HRESULT (__stdcall *GetThemePartSize)(
    HTHEME hTheme,
    __in_opt HDC hdc,
    int iPartId,
    int iStateId,
    __in_opt LPCRECT prc,
    enum THEMESIZE eSize,
    __out SIZE *psz
    );

HRESULT (__stdcall *DrawThemeBackground)(
    HTHEME hTheme,
    HDC hdc,
    int iPartId,
    int iStateId,
    LPCRECT pRect,
    __in_opt LPCRECT pClipRect
    );

HRESULT (__stdcall *DrawThemeEdge)(
    HTHEME hTheme,
    HDC hdc,
    int iPartId,
    int iStateId,
    LPCRECT pDestRect,
    UINT uEdge,
    UINT uFlags,
    __out_opt LPRECT pContentRect
    );

HRESULT (__stdcall * CloseThemeData)(
    HTHEME hTheme
    );
```

.cpp

```
OpenThemeData = (HTHEME (__stdcall *)(
        HWND hwnd,
        LPCWSTR pszClassList
        )) GetProcAddress (DllHandle, "OpenThemeData") ;

GetThemePartSize = (HRESULT (__stdcall *)(
        HTHEME hTheme,
        __in_opt HDC hdc,
        int iPartId,
        int iStateId,
        __in_opt LPCRECT prc,
        enum THEMESIZE eSize,
        __out SIZE *psz
        )) GetProcAddress (DllHandle, "GetThemePartSize") ;

DrawThemeBackground = (HRESULT (__stdcall *)(
        HTHEME hTheme,
        HDC hdc,
        int iPartId,
        int iStateId,
        LPCRECT pRect,
        __in_opt LPCRECT pClipRect
        )) GetProcAddress (DllHandle, "DrawThemeBackground") ;

DrawThemeEdge = (HRESULT (__stdcall *)(
        HTHEME hTheme,
        HDC hdc,
        int iPartId,
        int iStateId,
        LPCRECT pDestRect,
        UINT uEdge,
        UINT uFlags,
        __out_opt LPRECT pContentRect
        )) GetProcAddress (DllHandle, "DrawThemeEdge") ;

CloseThemeData = (HRESULT (__stdcall * )(
        HTHEME hTheme
        )) GetProcAddress (DllHandle, "CloseThemeData") ;
```

Everything works nicely now, also on Win2K